# Meaning of "meta-"

Tags: meaning

I am trying to figure out the meaning of prefix "Meta-" in English.

1. Quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)

   > Meta- (from Greek: μετά = "after",
   >   "beyond", "with", "adjacent", "self"),
   >   is a prefix used in English (and other
   >   Greek-owing languages) to indicate a
   >   concept which is an abstraction from
   >   another concept, used to complete or
   >   add to the latter.
   >
   > In epistemology, the prefix meta is
   >   used to mean *about (its own category)*.
   >   For example, metadata are data about
   >   data (who has produced them, when,
   >   what format the data are in and so
   >   on). Also, metamemory in psychology
   >   means an individual's knowledge about
   >   whether or not they would remember
   >   something if they concentrated on
   >   recalling it. Furthermore, metaemotion
   >   in psychology means an individual's
   >   emotion about his/her own basic
   >   emotion, "or somebody else's basic
   >   emotion".
   >
   > Another, slightly different
   >   interpretation of this term is "about"
   >   but not "on" (exactly its own
   >   category). For example, in linguistics
   >   a grammar is considered as being
   >   expressed in a metalanguage, or a sort
   >   of language for describing another
   >   language (and not itself). Any subject
   >   can be said to have a meta-theory
   >   which is the theoretical consideration
   >   of its meta-properties, such as its
   >   foundations, methods, form and
   >   utility.

   I was wondering what is the slightly
   difference between "*about (its own
   category)*" and "'about' but not
   'on' (exactly its own category)"?
2. My original problem is to understand
   the meaning of "metalogic" and
   "logic". Quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalogic):

   > Metalogic is the study of the
   >   metatheory of logic. While logic is
   >   the study of the manner in which
   >   logical systems can be used to decide
   >   the correctness of arguments,
   >   metalogic studies the properties of
   >   the logical systems themselves.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)
   >   According to Geoffrey Hunter, while
   >   logic concerns itself with the "truths
   >   of logic," metalogic concerns itself
   >   with the theory of "sentences used to
   >   express truths of logic."[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalogic)
   >
   > The basic objects of study in
   >   metalogic are formal languages, formal
   >   systems, and their interpretations.
   >   The study of interpretation of formal
   >   systems is the branch of mathematical
   >   logic known as model theory, while the
   >   study of deductive apparatus is the
   >   branch known as proof theory.

   In this case, is it correct to understand 
   "meta-X" as some study that treat
   something (here logical system) as a
   whole without going inside it,
   whereas "X" study the same thing by
   going inside it?
3. How would you explain the relation
   between "metaphysics" and "physics",
   and between
   "[meta-stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)" and
   "[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.
A simple example: I could look at a sequence of numbers and make a new sequence of numbers in which each number is the difference between two consecutive numbers from the first sequence:

- `1, 4, 7, 2` (sequence 1)
- `3, 3, 5` (sequence 2: sequential subtraction, with as its object sequence 1)

Then I could make sequence 3, with de differences between the numbers from sequence 2:

- `0, 2` (sequence 3: sequential subtraction, with as its object sequence 2)

Sequence 2 does with sequence 1 exactly the same thing (sequential subtraction) as what sequence 3 does with sequence 2. Both the operations carried out by 2 and 3 can be defined by the same name, sequential subtraction. We could say that 3 operates on a meta-level in relation to 2. We could say that 3 is meta-2. In logical language, we could define 2 as `SeqSub(sequence 1)`, and 3 as `SeqSub(SeqSub(sequence 1))`. As you see, 2 is nested within 3.

On the other hand, consider grammar and normal language. Normal language describes the world, ideas, anything. Grammar describes, too, but it only describes language, not the world or anything. Grammar could be called meta-language. In this manner, we could call anything meta-x as long as x is a theory and meta-x is a theory about x, even if x and meta-x operate in different ways. X should be something vaguely similar to a theory, some abstract operation.

(You could even use meta- with things that aren't theories or abstract operations, but that is normally not done, except as a joke — suppose you had a brush to clean the floor, and a rag to clean the brush; then you might jokingly call your rag a meta-cleaner.)

Now what is the difference between grammar and sequence 3? We could say that grammar does not do *exactly* the same thing with language as what language does with its object, because grammar cannot, for example, refer to a physical thing directly. I think this what your quote means, the difference between identical operation on the one hand and similar-but-not-identical operation on the other. Sequential subtraction = sequential subtraction; grammar is a language, but language is not always grammar. In logical language, we could describe language as `Describes(world)`, and grammar as `GrammaticallyAnalyses(Describes(world))`. They are nested, but in two slightly different ways.

Of course this distinction between "identical" and "similar" depends on definitions, which may be somewhat arbitrary. So I do not have full confidence in its strength and meaningfulness.

---

2.
I think I can feel what you mean, but I am not sure I'd phrase it like that.

I'd put metalogic in the second category mentioned above — similar to but not exactly the same as — but I am not sure. The reason why it is called "meta-" is that logic studies language and thinking, which makes logic an abstract operation and a theory; and metalogic studies logic, so that it is on a meta-level in relation to logic. Note that meta-x is always relative to its object: metalogic is not "meta-" in relation to, say, pottery.

---

3.
[Edited] In "metaphysics", the prefix "meta-" is used in its original sense in ancient Greek, which is here "after". Aristotle wrote the Physica, which were about the workings of nature: physis/phusis is Greek for nature. And he wrote the Metaphysica, which he called "The [books/bookrolls] about prime philosophy" — physics was the secondary philosophy. Later Greek scholars catalogued this work as "ta meta ta PHusika": "the things after the Physica", because they came after his Physica in their catalogue. Because his Metaphysica were about causality and other principles at work behind the physical world, it seems people later interpreted the "meta-" in Metaphysica as meaning "on a higher level than", and that is where our use of "meta-" came from.

---

4.
Stackoverflow is a website with questions and answers about programming. Meta-Stackoverflow is a website with questions and answers about Stackoverflow. So M-SO operates on SO the same way as SO operates on programming. In logical language, SO is SO(programming), and M-SO is SO(SO(programming)). You see how one is again nested within the other? That is why it is called Meta-Stackoverflow and not Newname.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, meta-X seems to be the same as a mathematics concept called Higher-order function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function?

Comment: I mean under the assumption that X can always be interpreted as a function?

Comment: Hmm, if I understand higher-order functions correctly, they are not the same. Meta-x is a specific type of higher-order function, with the additional condition that it can only be so called when it is a function that operates on a function similar to itself. So if f(x)=3x, and g(f)=3f, we have a meta-relationship; but if f(x)=3x, and h(f)=f^2, it is just a higher-order relation. How similar f and g need to be (here they are exactly identical) is open to debate, though I'd say "identical" in mathematics. Correct me if I understood higher-order functions incorrectly.

Comment: @Tim: Note also that meta- is not usually used mathematics, as far as I know. // You could also define meta- as a recursive function.

Comment: Yes, your understanding about higher order function is correct. So in mathematical language, for g to be meta, g and f have to be similar enough, and that's why you prefer to use recursive function , a special kind of higher order function, to "define" meta-.

Comment: I think I should say a recursive function is not a higher order function. Although similar, they are different as to whether their arguments are again functions.

Comment: I think you've got it. Note that meta- is usually a recursive function with only one level of recursion: meta-f is f(f(x)) rather than f(f(f(x))). I think I'd call f(f(f(x))) meta-meta-f, and so on. But remember that meta- is not really a mathematics term.

Comment: So yes you could say a recursive function is a type of higher-order function, but a higher-order function is not necessarily a recursive function, since there exist other types of higher_order function.

Comment: @Cerberus: to my knowledge too (I’m a logician), meta-logic (and relatedly, meta-mathematics, meta-theory, etc.) are the most widespread usages of meta- in mathematics.  But I feel (and I *think* most mathematicians would feel similarly) that Tim’s suggestion of higher-order functions would be a much more reasonable thing to call “meta-functions” — your use of “meta-*f*” for the iterate(s) of *f* doesn’t quite feel right.  Maybe that’s just me, though…  (Great answer in general, in any case!)

Comment: @PLL: metamathematics is used much more than metalogic.  Metamathematics is a part of mathematical logic and so is logic, metalogic is just a normal part of logic (an axiomatisation of a theory is itself axiomatisable, e.g., using logical frameworks).  @Cerberus: there are both recursive and non-recursive instances of both first-order and higher-order functions.

Comment: @Charles: you’re absolutely right, I should have named metamathematics as the main one and metalogic under the related forms.  Amusing you mention logical frameworks: I’ve been working quite a bit with them (and related embeddings) recently, which I guess is why metalogic, metalanguage, metatheory feel more natural to me at the moment than the more widely used metamathematics.

Comment: p.s. @Charles: I’m not sure if you’ve already recognised me from my initials — in case not, I’m also on MO, with interests not dissimilar to yours, though a bit more towards the category-theoretic; I’m also currently on the same page of the users list as you.

Comment: @PLL: I don't think I'd ever looked at your user page on MO before. A CMU alumni: were you there when Andrej Bauer was?  I can't say I'm on MO very often these days - I was spending far too long there and cut back.

Comment: @Charles: not quite — I arrived after he left — but he came back to visit a couple of times while I was there, so I do sort of know him still as “family”.  Re spending too much time on MO, *.stackexchange etc.: I hear you, I hear you!  :-/

Comment: @PLL, @Charles: Yuck, I messed up with the mathematics — I knew it. Because I half-suspected that mathematics used meta- in a somewhat different, technical sense, I tried to emphasise that my definition wasn't to be used there — too bad I felt I needed to explain the non-mathematical definition by analogy to something mathematical. How should I fix this? I believe that my explanation does fit the use of meta- outside mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow has questions about a topic. Meta-StackOverflow has questions about the questions in StackOverflow - for example, "is this question on topic?". X and Meta-X usually have similar relationships.

Logic is (roughly) about formal reasoning. Meta-logic is reasoning about logic, or why logic works.

Also, the relationship between physics and metaphysics and other similar pairs of words doesn't follow these "rules", and have independent definitions; you should look at their definitions and ignore the common root.

This is my admittedly informal understanding. I don't have a more formal understanding, but I don't have any practical problems with the concept either. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When meta- is typically prefixed to something being used as a *technical* term, it roughly means "higher ordered".

This means that if there is a sequence which itself contains a sequence, one can talk about the internal sequence as a "higher ordered" sequence or a "meta-sequence".

As ggambett mentions, Meta-StackOverflow is for discussion about StackOverflow.  StackOverflow is only about discussing programming problems, while the higher-order discussion is about discussing the discussion of programming problems.

Likewise if one were to try to talk about the commentary on StackOverflow in a similar manner, it could easily be construed as meta-meta-StackOverflow discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The Greek preposition meta has a lot of meanings, I would say it has gone wild.
Meta- can mean after. Aristotle's metaphysics was a book written after his physics.
In metaphysics he dealt with things beyond physics.

In the linguistic term metathesis meaning that a consonant changes its position before or after a vowel as in bird and to breed - in metathesis meta- expresses the idea of change.

I could add more examples where meta- has still other meanings.

So, when you have a Greek foreign word with meta- you have to get information about the meaning of meta-. Etymonline is good for such questions.