# What is the opposite of the "sub" prefix?

Tags: word-choice, prefixes

The term `subcategories` refers to lower level categories.

Which term should I use to refer to higher level categories?

Does `supercategories` sound right?

Comment: I came to this post after thinking about what would the opposite of "Sub-Saharan", i.e. countries above the Sahara. Geographically, the only defined term for that region is North Africa. If talking about it relative to the Sahara, though, is there a suitable prefix? Would "Sur-" as GEdgar answered below be correct?

Comment: Prefix "super" is common.  But note that the opposite of "subtitles" is "surtitles", the translation shown above the stage during operas sung in a foreign language.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a native speaker! <br><br> I was wondering if it could be used "up" in this case. <br><br> Examples: Top down and bottom up, up-grade and down-grade, upbeat and downbeat, upwards and downwards.. etc. So if you have a sub-project does it sound weird to call its superproject an "up-project", as super is also used for bigger/better/more-performative.. ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`Supercategories` is technically correct.

There are also `subscript` and `superscript` to back this example.

Comment: And for those of us in Computer Science, subclasses and superclasses. http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/subclasses.html

Comment: @Ben Hocking If subcategories are viewed from the point of inheritance then correct. Although it is a matter of perspective.

Comment: Supercategories may be technically correct, following the -script and -classes analogue, but parent categories sounds better to me in this case.

Comment: @Philoto, I did not mean to imply that subclasses and superclasses _were_ subcategories and supercategories, merely that they followed the same pattern as subscript/superscript that @Third Idiot gave.

Comment: @Hugo following that reasoning, subcategories should be child categories?

Comment: *super-superscripts*, and *sub-subscripts*? Does any DTP software support such things? What about even higher/lower?

Comment: @AttackingHobo Not necessarily. You don't say child folders.. Well, not in English anyway.

Comment: So airplanes could be called supermarines? I like it.

Answer (score 16):

For folders the term *parent folder* is usually used. And since categories are quite similar to folders, you may want to use *parent category* for higher-level categories. Or you can use *upper-level categories*.

Answer (score 6):

Movies often have subtitles, translated texts below the picture.  When opera productions project translated texts above the stage, they are called **surtitles**.

Comment: What about translated texts on the left/right of the picture, e.g. for some vertical scripts, like Hudum Mongol script?

Comment: I agree. 'sur-' as a prefix can be used almost everywhere as an opposite of the 'sub-' prefix. It is however extremely uncommon to see it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is no *defined* prefix or word to be an *opposite* of "**sub**".

**However**, the higher level for "subcategories" is simply **categories** and the lower level is **sub-subcategories** and to go a third level down is **sub-sub-subcategories** and so on.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You're quite right, for OP's context (*categories*) it's meaningless to talk about a prefix for a higher-level category than the top one. He just has to go through all lower levels and add an extra *sub-* to each, since the original *category* has turned out to be a *subcategory*!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you for taking the effort to explain my answer. I appreciate your input and I am glad to be part of this community.

Comment: np - I hope you'll grace our pages more in future. Don't worry too much about where the votes go (or don't, in your case here). Sometimes a more 'interesting' answer does get upvoted over a most 'accurate' one, but that's just democracy in action for you.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix that springs to mind for me is ***[meta-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta-)*** which I believe I picked up from reading *Gödel Escher Bach* by Douglas Hofstadter. He even uses it as a standalone word.

And coincidentally enough in the RELATED box for this question is [the opposite question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12162/what-is-the-opposite-of-meta)!

Comment: Hofstadter's later *Metamagical Themas* (monthly column in *Scientic American*, subsequently published as a fascinating single-volume) is full of musings where he starts at the 'day-to-day' level, and ends up considering things from some higher 'meta-perspective'. Brilliant graphic on the inside front cover, if you ever come across a copy.

Comment: @Fumble: I actually went out and bought that one after finishing GEB years ago (-:

Comment: I thought of meta- as well, but it's tied to something that is an abstraction and that might operate under different rules. So while snakes are a subcategory of reptiles, I wouldn't call reptiles a meta-category.

Comment: @Wayne: I think it's just a case of *sub-* having various opposites depending on the sense and root it's prefixed to and all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an antonym for "sub" since we use "sub" to talk about something which is a level down from something else. For example, "sub-category" is a category within a category. If you have to go further, you may use "sub-sub category." But in the end, the only category above all of these is simply a "category."

If you were to refer to the first category from which the "sub-category" and "sub-sub category" are taking birth, you may do so with "main category."

Hope I answered your question.

I recommend the following sites for great grammar info:

http://www.queens-english-society.com

http://englishisducksoup.com