# "Catch my drift" What was its origins?

Tags: expressions

Is it true that the expression "catch my drift " comes from the blizzard of 1888?
The drifts were so high that store owners put signs on top of drifts so customers could locate their businesses.

Comment: 1849: https://books.google.com/books?id=a4RHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA728&dq=%22catch+my+drift%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinlcbFn6bsAhUWJjQIHYx4AaQ4FBDoATAHegQIBxAC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and origin of "if you catch my drift"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/meaning-and-origin-of-if-you-catch-my-drift)