# What does 'meta' mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I referred to the *urban dictionary* and it says **meta** means something *used to characterize something that is characteristically self-referential.* 
But I'm still confused. Cause I don't see any difference between **English Language & Usage text** and **English Language & Usage meta**

Comment: Have you looked in a regular dictionary? It's a good bet that the formal use of a word on a site dedicated to the English language reflects one of the traditional meanings of the term, not a recent slang usage.

Comment: By English Language & Usage text, do you mean this site?  And English Language & Usage meta you're referring to this site's Meta site?  If so, the main site is for subject matter questions (topics covered in the site's definition and scope).  The Meta site is for questions about the operation of the main site (site policy questions, how to deal with posting issues concerning specific questions, things related to managing and maintaining the main site, etc.).  "Meta" refers to information about, or characteristics of, something else, as opposed to the content of the something else.

Comment: Also related: [Meaning of “meta-”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8432) (the prefix)

Comment: You should read this Help Center article: [What is Meta?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 0):

Meta means something "abstract" beyond logical explanation.

Comment: No it doesn't.  It is perfectly logical.

Comment: @Chenmunka I agree it's logical too, after I read [When your 10-year old boy says “It’s meta,” what does it mean? In what situation and of what sort of object they use this phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48576/when-your-10-year-old-boy-says-it-s-meta-what-does-it-mean-in-what-situation)